# How to throttle CPU on a Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, cpu

How to throttle CPU on a Mac?

I want to throttle CPU so that I can extend the battery life on a single charge.

Device: MBP 2015. Running Majove.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to different SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1412184/how-to-throttle-cpu-on-a-mac